# Python Bot Import Panda

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, discord.py

So i trying to use pandas in python bot from a excel sheet. see below table is a sample of excel with 4 columns and 10000+ rows with multiple sheets.

```
Name       Marks    Rank    School
Student1    655      1     Cambridge
Student2    345      2     Cambridge
Student3    554      3     Cambridge
Student4    847      4     St Peter
Student5    343      5     Cambridge
Student6    546      6     St Peter
Student7    755      7     St Peter
Student8    465      8     St Peter
Student9    467      9     Cambridge
```

So i tried all pandas examples found in google search. but everything shows results in console or bash file.

```
import xlrd

df = pd.read_excel('results.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
print(df[df["Name"] == "Student5"])
```

So how to get info about a particular student in discord channel.

example `student5`

```
Name       Marks    Rank    School

Student5    343      5     Cambridge
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with discord but you can get the result as a numpy array:

```
myarray = df[df["Name"] == "Student5"].values
```